# Spectral analysis of a $d$-regular graph

Tags: self-learning, laplacian, spectral-graph-theory

Given $d$-regular graph $G=(V, E)$, the adjacency matrix $A$, and the normalized Laplacian $L=I-\dfrac{1}{d}A$, prove that for any vector $\vec{x}\in \mathbf{R^{|V|}}$:
$$ \vec{x}L\vec{x}^t=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_{(u,v)\in E}(x_u-x_v)^2 $$

$u$ and $v$ are vertices, and $x_u$ and $x_v$ are values of the vector $\vec{x}$ corresponding to the vertices.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: I don't uderstand. What are $x_u$ $x_v$?

Comment: I edited the question to give more clarity.

Comment: A good starting place is writing the left side as a summation. Namely, $\vec{x}L \vec{x}^T = \sum_{i, j} x_i (\delta_{i, j} - A_{i, j}/d) x_{j}$ where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kroenecker delta. Note that if $A$ is the adjacency matrix then $\sum_{i, j} x_{i} A_{i, j} x_{j} = \sum_{(u, v) \in E} x_{u} x_{v}$.

Comment: So it seems this question needs even more clarification/correction. First, it's missing a factor of $1/2$ on the RHS. Second, you should define what $d$ is. Third, the Laplacian should be defined as $L = d-A$ (assuming you provide the correct definition of $d$).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Yes, I forgot to add the $\dfrac{1}{d}$ factor. $d$ is the regularity degree of the graph, as I stated in the title. The Laplacian could be rewritten as $L=\dfrac{1}{d}*(dI-A)$ if it would simplify things.

Comment: I mean you should define what $d$ is in terms of $A$. Also you multiplied the RHS by $1/d$ when you should have multiplied it by $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have a graph with $N$ vertices whose connections are defined by the adjacency matrix $A$. Namely, vertex $i$ is connected to vertex $j$ if $A_{ij} =1$ and if $i$ and $j$ are not connected then $A_{ij}=0$. Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix defined as $D = \operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{deg}(A)_1, \operatorname{deg}(A)_2, \ldots,\operatorname{deg}(A)_N )$, where $\operatorname{deg}(A)_k$ is the degree of vertex $k$. By definition, this degree is $\operatorname{deg}(A)_k \equiv  \sum_{\ell=1}^{N} A_{k\ell}$. For a $d$-regular graph, we have $\deg(A)_k = d$ for all $k$, but we will work most generally here.

We define the Laplacian as $L \equiv D - A$. Defining the row vector $\textbf{x}^{T} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N)$, we then have
\begin{align}
\textbf{x} L \textbf{x}^{T} & = \sum_{i, j=1}^{N} x_{i} L_{ij} x_{j} = \sum_{i, j=1}^{N} x_{i} (\delta_{ij} \operatorname{deg}(A)_{j} - A_{ij}) x_{j}\\
& = \sum_{i, j=1}^{N} x_{i} \delta_{ij} \sum_{\ell=1}^NA_{j\ell}x_{j} - \sum_{i, j=1}^N x_{i}A_{ij} x_{j}\\
& = \sum_{i, \ell=1}^{N} x_{i}A_{i\ell}x_{i} - \sum_{i, \ell=1}^N x_{i}A_{i\ell} x_{\ell}\\
& = \sum_{i, \ell=1}^{N} A_{i\ell}(x_i^2 - x_i x_{\ell})\\
\end{align}
In the second equality, we used the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$. In the first term of the fourth equality, we summed over the $j$ index and in the  second term of the fourth equality, we switched the dummy summation variable $j$ with $\ell$.

Now, because $A$ is the adjacency matrix for an unweighted graph, we have $A = A^T$. And thus $\sum_{i, \ell =1}^N A_{i\ell} x_i^2 = \sum_{i, \ell = 1}^N A_{i \ell} x_{\ell}^2$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
\textbf{x} L \textbf{x}^{T} & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, \ell = 1}^NA_{i \ell}(x_i^2 + x_{\ell}^2 - 2 x_{i} x_{\ell})\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, \ell = 1}^NA_{i \ell}(x_i- x_{\ell})^2.
\end{align}
With $A$ the adjacency matrix, $A_{i\ell}$ is only non-zero when the connection $(i, \ell)$ is in the set of edges $E$. So we obtain

\begin{align}
\textbf{x} L \textbf{x}^{T}  = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ (i, \ell) \in E}(x_i- x_{\ell})^2.
\end{align}

Comment: This resolves the question, thank you so much for the explanation!